# How can I import a CSS stylesheet into Atom content?

Tags: css, atom-feed

I'm publishing an Atom feed, and I'd like to start including basic CSS for the content. Of course I'm not expecting it to be used by every reader, but it would be nice to support the readers that can use styles.

Is there any way to include CSS in Atom content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include inline `<style>` blocks as part of each entry's body, but this rather defeats the entire purpose of RSS/Atom feeds IMO (and is likely to be filtered out by many readers). Use standard elements like `blockquote`, `em`, `img`, etc. and let the reader handle the rest.